# Bootstrap selectpicker is duplicated after refresh in cloned div

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a bootstrap selectpicker:

```
<div id="maindiv">
  <div class="hidden">
     <select class="form-control selectpicker communitySelect " multiple="true">
        <option selected value="0">All Communities</option>
     </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I try to clone this hidden div and try to add/remove selectpicker options in cloned div:

```
 var $pickerdiv = $("div.hidden").clone();
 $pickerdiv.removeClass("hidden");
 $("#maindiv").append($pickerdiv);

 var $communitySelector = $pickerdiv.find(".selectpicker");
 $communitySelector.selectpicker();
 $communitySelector.find('option').remove();
 $communitySelector.selectpicker('refresh');
```

But after selectpicker refresh method it is duplicated on UI:
https://jsfiddle.net/v660Lb4p/8/

So how to resolve this?

**RESOLVED:**
Bootstrap selectpicker plugin applied automatically to elements with selectpicker class. So I removed this class and... its working now!
https://jsfiddle.net/v660Lb4p/16/

Comment: no it's not? The second selectpicker is empty (as per `.remove()`) (?)

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai the second selectpicker is empty and the first one isn't hidden, OP is expecting `clone()` to return a clone of the object so `cloneddiv.removeClass("hidden")` shouldn't affect the original div

Answer (score 4):

We need to change selectpicker class to another class name so that this issue has been resolved.
I also work with bootstrap-select and found this issue because of selectpicker("refresh").
so I changed class name and it is working fine. :-)

This is already reported on bootstrap-select github repository.
https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1413

Answer (score 0):

When you clone an object, you may pass additional parameters as per documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents

> A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along
>   with the elements. As of jQuery 1.4, element data will be copied as
>   well.

So my suggestion is to use the following line:

```
 var $pickerdiv = $("div.hidden").clone(true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v660Lb4p/13/

Comment: your method did work, but why ? there aren't any event handlers nor data elements on the original ?

Comment: You are cloning a JS-Selectpicker, not pure HTML. So all properties are still hooked up. If you clone data and events, then you get a cloned version, not a _mirror_ version.

Comment: But now I can't append new option: https://jsfiddle.net/v660Lb4p/15/. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shame it still hasn't been fixed in 2022!
BTW, the following worked for me, so I hope this can help someone else as well:

```
    var refName = $.trim( $('#ref_name').val() );

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "{{ route('myroute') }}",
        data: {
            'name' : refName,
             _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
        success: function(results){

/*  ---------------     Here is the main part ----------------*/
            $('#my-selectpicker').selectpicker("destroy");

            // remove all options of the select element
            $('#my-selectpicker option').each(function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });

            $.each(results, function( index, value ) {
                $('#reference').append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
            });

            $('#my-selectpicker').addClass('selectpicker').selectpicker("render");

/*  -------------     Here is the main part ---------------------*/
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
            console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```