# Component not showing data on pressing back

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

The Following code displays the list of countries when component is rendered for the first time.

```
<select onChange={this.handleLocation} data-live-search="true" className="selectpicker" data-selected-text-format="count" data-size="7" title="Select Country" >
                                    { getNames() && getNames().map(
                                        (e, id) => {
                                            return <option key={e} >{e}</option>
                                        })
                                    }
                                </select>
```

Note: `bootstrap-select` is used.

When component is loaded for the first time, the list of countries are displayed properly. But when button is clicked, I am redirecting to another component using

```
this.props.push('/searchresults')
```

After pressing back, the component is loaded perfectly but the list of countries are not rendering to the component.

Whats wrong with my code.

FYI: npm i country-list --> Package to get countries

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the component wont render selectpicker after it is mounted. We have to update the dropdown on component mounts.

The Problem is with bootstrap-select library that is being used in this project

I have select dropdown with class of `selectpicker`.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713747/bootstrap-selectpicker-is-duplicated-after-refresh-in-cloned-div) question, I found that the selectpicker class is no longer needed for dropdown. Instead i trigged `selectpicker` library in `componentDidMount` everytime.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-select';

componentDidMount(){
$('select').selectpicker()   <<-- This triggers the library on component mount
}
```

So the component loads selectpicker everytime it rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove return on the function map also your tag option attribute key must be unique, if even remove function getNames properly didn't any problem on your code. I hope useful.

```
{getNames().map((e, id) => (<option key={id} >{e}</option>))}
```

Comment: I didn't see output on first render itself, As per this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999671/map-function-not-working-in-react
its mandatory to have return inside map

Comment: sorry for the delay and my mistake, exact good point, curly brackets is wrong so use parentheses  {getNames().map((e, id) => (<option key={id} >{e}</option>))}

Comment: I figured out that the problem is from CSS actually. The element exists after pressing back in source code. the css is not loading properly from style.css in public folder.

Comment: Congratulations, of course, if you want, you can use my code to compile your code. Good luck